# Probability of getting at least 2 numbers smaller of the average of n numbers if you pick 3 of them

Tags: probability, math-software

I have got the numbers "   13,  15,  12,  9,  6,  3,  5,  12,  17,  10,  12,  9,  6,  8,  10,  8,  10" and I have to find ,if I randomly pick three of these
numbers, what is the probability that at least two of them are smaller than the
average of all seventeen?

The average is 9.7 = 10. I have 8 numbers smaller than 10 . The probability of getting at least 2 smaller than the average is P(of getting 2 smaller and 1 greater) + P(of getting 3 smaller and no greater) so is (8/17 * 7/16 *9/15 )+
(8/17 * 7/17 * 6/17 ) .
I am not sure if that is the correct way . Can anyone tell me if am right?

Comment: Note that $9.7=10$ is false.  It does not change the result as there are no numbers smaller than $10$ that are not also smaller than $9.7$, but it would if you were considering smaller than or equal to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much!  It's just that you can pick those 2 smaller + 1 not smaller in 3 different ways, because you can pick that not smaller one as your first, second, or third. So, you get:

3* (8/17 * 7/16 *9/15 )+ (8/17 * 7/16 * 6/15 )

(also note you had 17 in the denominator for each of the terms in the second expression, which wasn't right, but that was just a typo on your part since you had it right in the first term)

Comment: @PinelopiConstantinou  Please check my answer again ... you need to add the factor of 3 for the first term!

Comment: yeap i checked it , thank you again!!

Comment: @PinelopiConstantinou You're welcome! ... how'd you make out on that matches puzzle?

Comment: nothing yet ..I decided to leave it at the end because its the difficult one. I can not deal with such kind of problems :p

Comment: done! :) if you have any other hints or why not the solution of the problem with the matches let me know! :)

Comment: @PinelopiConstantinou I just posted a start ...